# How to get all Calendar lists from entire site collection using JSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jsom

Is it possible to get all Calendar lists from entire SharePoint site collection using JSOM?

I want to get lists from sub sites also.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The CSOM does **not** provide a mechanism for querying data across multiple lists within a site collection, in other words, there is no client-side functional equivalent of the `SPSiteDataQuery` class. Despite that fact, it could be accomplished but the performance could be a real bottleneck here.

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve contact lists within a site collecion:

```
function enumWebs(rootWeb,propertiesToRetrieve, success,error)
{
   var result = [];
   var level = 0;
   ctx.load(rootWeb,propertiesToRetrieve);
   result.push(rootWeb);
   var colPropertiesToRetrieve = String.format('Include({0})',propertiesToRetrieve.join(',')); 
   var enumWebsInner = function(web,result,success,error) 
   {
      level++;
      var ctx = web.get_context();
      var webs = web.get_webs(); 
      ctx.load(webs,colPropertiesToRetrieve);
      ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function(){
            for(var i = 0; i < webs.get_count();i++){
                var web = webs.getItemAtIndex(i);
                result.push(web);
                enumWebsInner(web,result,success,error);
            }
            level--;
            if (level == 0 && success)
              success(result);  
        },
        error);
   };
   enumWebsInner(rootWeb,result,success,error);    
}


var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var rootWeb = ctx.get_site().get_rootWeb();
enumWebs(rootWeb,['Lists'],
   function(allWebs){
       var calendarLists = allWebs.map(function(web){
            var lists = web.get_lists().get_data().filter(function(list){
                 return list.get_baseTemplate() === 106;
            }); 
            return lists; 
       }); 

       //print results
       console.log(calendarLists.length + ' calendars were found in site collection');

   },
   function(sender,args){
      console.log(args.get_message());
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not get all calendar lists under a site collection at a time. You will have to query site by site. For example, If you make a GET request to below endpoint, it will return all calendar lists.

```
/_api/web/lists?$filter=BaseTemplate eq 106
```

So you have to make this GET request for all sites and sub sites.

**PS:** Template Id of calendar is 106. That's why you need to apply `$filter` equal `106`

Use my [SharePoint REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sp-rest-client/ojnaikgchcnginnmkmkonmdglhjikokd) to explore more.